# (jQuery & JavaScript) animate goes back to orgininal state

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

So I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#nexButton').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#nexButton').stop().animate({opacity: '1'},'fast'); 
            $('#nexButton').mouseleave(function(){
                $('#nexButton').stop().animate({opacity: '0.7'},'fast'); 
            });
    });

     $('#bacButton').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#bacButton').stop().animate({opacity: '1'},'fast'); 
            $('#bacButton').mouseleave(function(){
                $('#bacButton').stop().animate({opacity: '0.7'},'fast'); 
            });
    });

});
```

in my javascript and with the nexButton it runs perfect but with the bacbutton it  just go back to 0.7 opacity while I'm still on the button?! What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nexButton, #bacButton')
      .on('mouseenter', function(){
          $(this).animate({opacity: '1'}, 'fast'); 
      })
      .on('mouseleave', function(){
          $(this).animate({opacity: '0.7'},'fast'); 
      });
});
```

Here is the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/L4r90p99/4/).

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, and I tried your code directly but it still does only work well on the nexButton

Comment: I see it works on Fibble but I still doesn't work in my browser google chrome and firefox

Comment: I made a mistake in the spelling please check again the question